# How can the number of chromosome change during evolution

Tags: evolution

I found an explanation [here](http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2008/04/21/basics-how-can-chromosome-numb/), which is basically saying that sometimes the centromeres are duplicated, breaking a chromosome into two halves. But how could this propagate?  I don't think inbreeding is efficient enough for this mutation to become dominant, and it should take a lot of pregnancies for the mutants and the regular ones to produce an healthy offspring. Is the explanation in the link backed by any evidence?
Thank you!

By the way, do we know how many chromosomes did the latest common ancestor of human and chimpanzee have, and when did chimpanzee gain the extra pair of chromosomes (or when did we lose it)?

Comment: We cannot have direct evidence as the DNA of common ancestors have either not been found or are degraded to a point where it cannot be analyzed. However when looking at modern genomes we can do syntenic analysis and look at the [synteny](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/synteny-inferring-ancestral-genomes-44022) between chromosomes. Whether you believe it or not, the evidence is within our genome and many other genomes. All you need for it to take hold is an isolated population that is put under selective pressure.

Comment: @arax There are two different questions in your post. A post should always be limited to one question. I suggest that you get rid of the second one. You may ask it later.

Comment: @arax Speciation due to change in chromosomal number by hybridization between two species, yielding to a third species has typically be quite nicely studied. Would such an example answer your question?

Comment: Note btw that a change in chromosomal number is often (not always) associated with a shift in the ecological niche toward more extreme environments. Why is it so? Last time I heard of it, I have been told that nobody really knows why.

Comment: Someone asked and then deleted their comment, but to clarify, "direct evidence" in my comment would be intact, sequenceable genomic DNA from a Common Ancestor. Syntenic analysis provides inferential evidence of the events of translocation that have survived in evolution, but without the ability to compare to the actual data of the common ancestor, we can only infer the events.

Comment: This article may be useful.  The author goes into several ways that chromosomal rearrangements can go wrong resulting in a change in chromosome number. http://scienceblogs.com/pharyngula/2008/04/21/basics-how-can-chromosome-numb/